# Как сверстать activity с баннером внизу на android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Есть activity с двумя элементами:

1. **WebView** (на весь экран).
2. **ProgressBar** посередине(по умолчанию скрыт).

Нужно добавить баннер **AdView** от яндекса вниз экрана. Высота баннера при этом не фиксирована (AdSize.flexibleSize()), то есть высота webview должна изменяться взависимости от высоты adview.

Как это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/banner_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Элементы находятся в RelativeLayout

```
  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/img0"
    android:layout_above="@+id/img1"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:src="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Тут главное параметр "layout_alignParentBottom" для нижнего элемента, что указывает его расположение в низу. И "layout_above" - для верхнего, в котором ты указываешь id вьюхи, над которой он находится.

Comment: Благодарствую. Это работает